# Правильная структура данных

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я столкнулся с неожиданно неприятной проблемой. Вроде знаю как работать с обьектами а вроде хочу сделать это красиво и удобно что бы потом не возвращаться к этому вопросу.

У меня есть Schema для работы с MongoDB через Mongoose. Юзер сможет заполнять свою информацию в любой момент и в любом порядке. Так есть что бы подтвердить заявку нужно заполнить все поля но база будет хранить и не завершенные запросы для удобности пользователей.

Для этого я добавил еще один массив обьектов который будет служить:

- Списком всех полей
- Описанием поля для пользователя
- Индекс полей что бы сверить с данными из базы и найти что еще не заполнено, после чего продолжить процесс заполнения с последней точки

Проблема в том, что если просто сделать обьект с обьектами я не знаю как удобно запрашивать информацию по индексу И полю. Так есть мне нужно что бы было возможно запросить информацию про каждое поле типа:

Эй, скажи мне что такое `name`.

- `Пожалуйста: Your name`

А что под номером 3?

- `field: "age"`

Покажи мне список полей с важностью 1.

```
1: {field: "name", type: "String", description: "Your name", rank: 1},
2: {field: "nickname", type: "String", description: "Nickname that will be shown to others", rank: 1}
```

Пример списка:

```
1: {field: "name", type: "String", description: "Your name", rank: 1},
2: {field: "nickname", type: "String", description: "Nickname that will be shown to others", rank: 1},
3: {field: "age", type: "Number", description: "Your age", rank: 2},
```

Даже учитывая что можно заполнять в любом порядке важно иметь очередность полей что бы можно было пройтись по всем полям по порядку тем же `for` или `each`.

По-моему мой запрос выходит похож на что-то подобное базе данных, возможно локальной, а возможно мне стоило бы добавить эту информацию в БД? Я не уверен можно ли добавить подобную статическую информацию в схему, так что было бы интересно увидеть. Или обьясните мне чего я не понимаю, почему это так сложно понять для меня.

Спасибо за внимание, я уже не 1 час сижу пытаюсь понять что делать. Нашел `Map()`, который работает только для ключа и строки, не сильно полезно, а так же библиотеки [collection.js](http://www.collectionsjs.com/) и [Buckets JS](http://mauriciosantos.github.io/Buckets-JS/) которые выглядят неплохо, но я побаиваюсь использовать библиотеку для одного лишь списка. А так же JS базы данных: [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) и [TaffyDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/taffydb). Первая очень красивая, но у меня чувство что слишком большая для поставленной задачи. Вторая тоже предназначена для куда больших целей чем нужно. Может я не прав, хотелось бы тогда услышать почему.

Comment: Напишите свой класс, который бы хранил список и в методе query инкапсулировал функциональность поиска в списке по каким угодно параметрам.

Comment: список  у Вас храниться в массиве?

Comment: @Дмытрык на данный момент в обьекте, но в конечном счете для меня это не важно, лишь бы работало как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

**TaffyDB**

Функционал почти как у обычных SQL поддерживает (CRUD), упрощенная выборка и обновление.

```js
// Create DB and fill it with records
var friends = TAFFY([{
    "id": 1,
    "gender": "M",
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Smith",
    "city": "Seattle, WA",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "gender": "F",
    "first": "Kelly",
    "last": "Ruth",
    "city": "Dallas, TX",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "gender": "M",
    "first": "Jeff",
    "last": "Stevenson",
    "city": "Washington, D.C.",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "gender": "F",
    "first": "Jennifer",
    "last": "Gill",
    "city": "Seattle, WA",
    "status": "Active"
  }
]);

// Find John Smith, by ID
var id = friends({
  id: 1
});
console.log(id.first().first);
// Get an array of record ids
var cities = friends().select("id");
console.log(cities);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/taffydb/2.7.3/taffy-min.js"></script>
```

Реально проще уже некуда и мало весит.

```js
var cities = TAFFY([{
  name: "New York",
  state: "WA"
}, {
  name: "Las Vegas",
  state: "NV"
}, {
  name: "Boston",
  state: "MA"
}]);

cities.insert({
  name: "Portland",
  state: "OR"
});

console.log(cities({
  name: "Boston"
}).count());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/taffydb/2.7.3/taffy-min.js"></script>
```

---

**PouchDB**

Эта будет мощнее синхронизация с локальными и удаленными базами. Непрерывная работа с пользователем и ошибки на сервере её не пугают, сохраняет то что делал юзер и только когда может послать на сервер посылает, отказоустойчива.

```js
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Немного не так легко как с TaffyDB если нет удаленной базы,
// с другой стороны легко синхронизируется с сервером
//----------------------------------------------------------------

var db = new PouchDB('databaseName');
db.put(data)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res); /* handling result */
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err); /* errors handling */
  });

db.remove(data)
  .then(response => { /* handling result */ })
  .catch(err => { /* errors handling */ });

db.get(data)
  .then(doc => { /* do something with document */ })
  .catch(err => { /* errors handling */ });
console.log(db.info());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pouchdb/7.0.0/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
```

Можно почитать [тут](https://habr.com/post/342318/)